# Algebraic Number theory, why is $\mathcal{O}_K/p \cong p^k/p^{k+1}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Assume that $\mathcal{O}_K$ is the integer ring of number field $K$, $p$ is its prime ideal, why $\mathcal{O}_K/p \cong p^k/p^{k+1}$, in which $k$ is a positive integer? Is $p/p^{k+1}$ a ring? Could it be considered as the ideal of $\mathcal{O}_K/p^{k+1}$?

Comment: The isomorphism is one of $\mathcal{O}_K/\mathfrak{p}$-modules.

Comment: Please try to state the question in the title. "An abstract algebra question" is very vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Mummy pointed out, we are dealing with additive abelian groups morphisms (i.e modules over the integers).
In theorem (22.a), chapter 3 of Marcus' Number Fields there is the sketch of the proof of what you are saying. The point is that for unique factorization, for every $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, there is an $\alpha \in p^k \setminus p^{k+1}$. Then the mapping $ \varphi :\mathcal{O}_K \rightarrow p^k/p^{k+1} $ where $\varphi(x)= \alpha x+p^{k+1}$ (as a class) induces the isomoprhism that you are looking for. You should check that this mapping is onto and that the kernel is just $p$.